# Does it take time between when a service principal is created and when it can be used?

Tags: azure-service-principal, azure-ai, azure-secrets

Following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/secure-ai-services/4-exercise-secure-ai-services), I was able to create a service principal. However, I observed that when I tried to use the password of service principal, I got the following error.

```
ClientSecretCredential.get_token failed: Authentication failed: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1002) Authentication failed: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1002)
```

Strangely, the code worked after a few retries. Does it take time between when a service principal is created and when it can be used?

Comment: Yes it takes few minutes for the service principal to be created, there might be a delay

Comment: Did you get the ask of the issue, if yes I will post it as an answer?